# I want to use facebook connect in my website to register, login and comment on news articles or posts made by other users

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I would like to implement the following things in my website. I have done some extensive search over the internet but couldnt find and specific examples on how to implement them
I am developing this site in php using a mvc framework

1. Would like to have facebook registration on my website - users who have an account in facebook will get an option to use the details to register in my site, using their authentication I would pull the relavant details from their account and create a new account for them in my website. I would like to use facebook register fbml/fbjs in this case

   1. Would like to have facebook login used to login into my site. How to use the sessions is what I would like to know?
   2. I would like to make posts to the facebook-wall of the users registered in my site. Also if possible sent messages to them through my code whenever a new post is made to my site.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

For login and registration, you can check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/.

This one is for wall posts and you should be able to implement it in any language. It is given step by step.
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

Comment: thanks for the info, the link was good but have you got something that is more latest